# How to make a certificate chain that doesn't rely on the root certificate

Tags: certificate

I want to set up a certificate chain for a project im testing.

It will have the root certificate, then certificate A, then certificate B, etc.

Currently, with how im setting it up, if I dont have the root certificate, certificate B won't be valid. How can I have it so certificate B doesn't rely on the root certificate.

Here are the openSSL commands I've been using.

Create root certificate private key:
`openssl genrsa -out ca.key 4096`

Create root certificate: `openssl req -new -x509 -days 1826 -key ca.key -out ca.crt`

Create certificate A private key: `openssl genrsa -out ia.key 4096`

Create certificate A request: `openssl req -new -key ia.key -out ia.csr`

Create and sign certificate A to root: `openssl x509 -req -days 730 -in ia.csr -CA ca.crt -CAkey ca.key -set_serial 01 -out ia.crt`

For certificate B I do the same thing(but change the names of course and sign to certificate A instead of root).

But if I dont have certificate A or the Root, then certificate B won't work. How can I make it so certificate B doesn't rely on the root certificate or certificate A?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to ask how to validate a certificate chain without the root certificate? Or generate a certificate without a root?

Comment: I want to figure out how to validate a certificate without the root certificate @pedrofb

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood the question correctly, please check the answer

Answer (score 0):

A certificate is signed with the private key of the parent certificate. To validate the digital.signature you need the public key of the parent certificate. Therefore you can not validate a certificate chain without the root

Usually a client system that has to validate a certificate has a trust store with the root certificates of the accepted Certificate Authorities. Also a certificate use to have an special attribute containing a URL pointing to the parent certificate

Comment: Let me re-explain. On my computer, lets say I create multiple certificates. I have a root, a intermediate certificate and a certificate. If I dont have the root certificate on my computer. If I sent the certificate or the intermediate certificate to someone else, the certificate shows that it is invalid. Is there a way to prevent that without giving them the root certificate file manually, like combining both certificates together?

Comment: It is expected that you provide manually the root certificate to the other party. A certification chain can contain all the necessary certificates (for example in PEM format) but normally the root is not included and it is distributed by other means. This prevents the client from automatically trusting a certificate. The client must have a truststore with the root certificates that it actually trusts, so the behavior you describe is the expected one